# How can i make each div look like seperate block?

Tags: css, html

I am purely into Java programming , frankly  with very limited or no knowledge in css.

This is the image i want to achive to be shown .

[image]

This is the image , i have achivied currently .

[image]

Each check box content must look like the above image .

The plus symbols and the description , i can add that , but only i need how each checkbox can look like above content ??

This is my code for achveing that checkbox  dynamically

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseinner.length; i++) {
activateUiHTML.append('<div id="'+responseinner[i]+'" >') ;
activateUiHTML.append('<input type="checkbox" id="'+responseinner[i]+'"  name="'+responseinner[i]+'" value="'+responseinner[i]+'"/>'+responseinner[i]+"") ;
activateUiHTML.append('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp');
activateUiHTML.append('</div>') ;
}
```

Comment: I just want to clarify, what do you want to achieve? 3 checkboxes that are in a single line?

Comment: no , each check box must look like the first above picture .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

note the `style` property in the DIV tag

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseinner.length; i++) {
activateUiHTML.append('<div style="border: 1px solid Black;" id="'+responseinner[i]+'" >') ;
activateUiHTML.append('<input type="checkbox" id="'+responseinner[i]+'"  name="'+responseinner[i]+'" value="'+responseinner[i]+'"/>'+responseinner[i]+"") ;
activateUiHTML.append('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp');
activateUiHTML.append('</div>') ;
}
```

Comment: Pleasure - Please visit: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp - this is a good introduction to CSS - CSS is an integral part of Visual Web Development. Good luck